# Change "Refresh Linked Browsers" shortcut in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I want to change the default keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Enter) for the [Browser Link feature in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) to another key, but i can't find any options in the keyboard list.

if at all possible, how can i change it?

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported, since it doesn't show up in the list of commands under Keyboard options.  You could file a bug to http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Answer (score 4):

There is a user voice for this feature:

[Make shortcut for "Refresh Linked Browsers" changeable](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5346570-make-shortcut-for-refresh-linked-browsers-change)